# gsoap client multiple ethernets

Tags: linux, network-programming, gsoap

I have a linux system with two eth cards. eth0 and eth1. I am creating a client that sends
to endpoint 1.2.3.4.

I send my webservice with soap_call_ functions. How can I select eth1 instead of eth0?

the code is like that

soap_call_ns__add(&soap, server, "", a, b, &result);

How can I set inside the &soap variable the eth0 or the eth1?

(gsoap does not have a bind for clients... like soap_bind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for gsoap we need to manually bind(2) before connect(3) in tcp_connect

Answer (score 0):

You want outgoing packages from your host to take a specific route (in this case a specific NIC)? If that's the case, then you have to adjust kernels routing tables.

Shorewall has [excellent documentation](http://www.shorewall.net/MultiISP.html) on that kind of setup. You'll find there info about how to direct certain traffic through a particular network interface.

Comment: @cateof I've edited my answer and added a link to shorewall's howto. Please read the howto very carefully. Routing has always been a little bit tricky. :)